# Storage Access Framework as a "Private" (local-only) Folder/File Picker?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

My ultimate goal is to allow the user to select a folder to save a file to - the file is a video file that will be created at some point after the user has chosen the destination.
I am simply using the storage access framework picker to allow them to select a location for it to be saved in.

First of all, is there a way to allow a user to select only a folder (and not a file/filename)?
The best I can do right now is use the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` Intent in order to get a save location, however I do not really want to specify the filename in the SAF picker (this will be done back in the app)...

Secondly, after reading the [Storage Access Framework documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), and cobbling together some bits from a [few](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage) [code](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) [samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/StorageProvider/index.html), I've got a working DocumentsProvider which *almost* does what I want - which is to allow the user to browse their external storage (SD Card) directories for a suitable place to save a video file - by adding my own root which points to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to the queryRoots() method.

However, what I really want is for that to be my only root (at the minute I've also got Drive, Downloads etc.).
Is it possible to remove/hide other roots so it essentially becomes an application-specific file picker?
Or even show local storage only (perhaps the `Root.FLAG_LOCAL_ONLY` flag can help)?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you don't want any of the normal behaviors of the Storage Access Framework, why are you using it? There are [at least five file/directory choosers](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) available as open source libraries.

Comment: I like the native look/feel and, while I could, I didn't really feel like re-creating it myself. As I mentioned, I've almost got it how I'd like, but was looking for a way to show local roots only if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[API 21](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Storage) supports `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. This allows you to select the location once and then you can use the provided URI to manipulate its content.

```
private static final int LOCATION_CHOOSER_REQ_CODE = 4;

public void chooseLocation() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, LOCATION_CHOOSER_REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_CHOOSER_REQ_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();  // Use this URI to access files
        }
}
```